# Any way to add Android notification sounds just for your app?

Tags: android, notifications, ringtone

I want to be able to let the user choose from long notification sounds I've bundled with my app (as opposed to the short ones available by default). I could always install the notification sounds as being globally avaialble, but i'd like those new sounds i install only to be available for my app, so I'm not cluttering up my users' list of notification sounds for all apps

Comment: i would like to know how. if you did solve this please post the answer.